# what is the definition of 'worker' for dask yarn?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

The dask-yarn documentation has the following example.

```
from dask_yarn import YarnCluster
from dask.distributed import Client

# Create a cluster where each worker has two cores and eight GiB of memory
cluster = YarnCluster(environment='environment.tar.gz',
                      worker_vcores=2,
                      worker_memory="8GiB")
# Scale out to ten such workers
cluster.scale(10)

# Connect to the cluster
client = Client(cluster)
```

In the example, what is the definition of "worker"? Is it a node (i.e., piece of hardware)? Is it a process? What do I pass to `YarnCluster` and `cluster.scale`?

To be more concrete, say I have a cluster with 20 nodes, each of which has 8 CPUs and 32 GB of RAM, and I want to maximize resource usage. Do I have to set `worker_vcores = 8`, `worker_memory = 32`, and `cluster.scale(20)`? Or do different settings work; e.g., `worker_vcores = 4`, `worker_memory = 16`, and `cluster.scale(40)`?